# Github Integration with Checkmarx

Tags: github, continuous-integration, checkmarx

I am working on Github integration with Checkmarx, which is used for code safety scan. This method works just fine for the repository hosted on github.com (**External repository**), but does not work on **internal** repository hosted inside our company (github.XXX.com), in fact the connection always failed (cannot pass the repository authorization on Checkmarx).

I have checked both repository (internal and external) settings, they look the same to me. What is the difference between these two different repositories? Any suggestions? Thanks a lot for your help. ---John

Answer (score 1):

You can find the differences in configuration between your Git and GitHub here:
[Checkmarx - Configuring the Connection to a Source Control System](https://checkmarx.atlassian.net/wiki/display/KC/Configuring+the+Connection+to+a+Source+Control+System)

Just to summarize, in order to use your own Git you need to download GIT Installation Package and perform the installation on CxSAST Manager Server.

Good luck.

Comment: yaloner, Thanks for your response. I downloaed the GIT Installation package and installed it on CxSAST manager server. Checkmarx did scan the external repository codes but failed connection to internal repository.

Comment: A couple of things to check:  Your internal servers certificate could be self signed and https validation is failing, your internal project is listed as private and the client cannot download the codebase, or there is a firewall between the manager server and the internal Git repo that is blocking port 80 or 443.

Answer (score 0):

In 2020, you can use [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions).

CxSAST by Checkmarx is actually available directly as a GitHub Action in the new [Code Scanning Security feature](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-09-30-code-scanning-is-generally-available/), available since Sept. 30th 2020.

> GitHub code scanning is a developer-first, GitHub-native approach to easily find security vulnerabilities before they reach production.
> Today we're excited to announce that code scanning is generally available on GitHub.com.
>
> Code scanning is free for public repositories. Learn more about how to enable code scanning today.

You can select it in the Security tab of your (public) repository:

[image: select]

And it will create the GitHub Actions file for you:

[image: GitHub file]

Comment: The action is failing. Do we need to give some environment variable or need to configure the repo at some web portal?

Comment: @thepurpleowl Which action, the CxSAST specifically or the code scanning in general? How is it failing? DO you have a public URL illustrating the issue?

Comment: I was asking about credentials like `secrets.CHECKMARX_URL`, but where to get those values?

Comment: @thepurpleowl That depend on the third-party service you are activating for your code scanning GitHub Action. `secrets.CHECKMARX_URL` is a parameter of  https://github.com/marketplace/actions/checkmarx-cxflow-action (Checkmarx Server URL)