# Running Scans automated Checkmarx

Tags: powershell, checkmarx

I am running security and static code scan through checkmarx manually. Is it possible to run these scans like:

1. It takes code from git/vsts repos.
2. Upload to checkmarx.
3. Run complete scans and publish report through email.
4. Schedule these scans like once in a month or two.

Comment: This is probably possible. Please post the code you are trying to make work, tell what it does, and tell what you want it to do.

Comment: I haven't written any code but just want to know if it is possible. Thanks for your acknowledgement. Now  , how it is possible? Is there any Command Line to do this all or it is possible through UI?

Comment: I have more than 20 source code repos hosted on git and vsts. I want to schedule them in such a way that once in a month , source code in these repos can be automatedly get scanned and results published on some email. I hope the OBJECTIVE is clear.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free code writing service. People here will help work through problems with specific source code. Questions without source code usually go to https://superuser.com/ If you need to hire a programmer, you might try https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent

Comment: I am newer to Checkmarx and run all scans manually. Objective of this question was to know whether there is automated way or not which u answered in a good way. Secondary , I am not asking you to write a code for me :) , But a root path to do this activity. Thanks for everything.

Comment: Please ask to Checkmarx Ltd. regarding automating with their product. Their web site does not give any clues.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/64149964/6309

Answer (score 0):

You can automate the process with Azure DevOps (VSTS).

- Install the [Checkmarx](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=checkmarx.cxsast)  extension.
- Create a new build pipeline, in the Get Sources choose your Git repo.
- Add a "Checkmarx" task:

[image]

- Configure the fields in the task.
- Run the build.
- [Subscribe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/alerts-and-notifications?view=tfs-2017) to get an email alert when the build finished.
- In the build "Triggers" choose on "Scheduled" to run the builds automatically every month:

[image]

Comment: I think this is the last option, for this , your code should be the part of either TFS or  Git. Secondary, If you have 20+ repoS then you have to create same no of build definitions and run them accordingly. Is it possible if i can run all project whether they are on TFS or Git simultaneously through powershell or some commandline way out.  Thanks!!

Comment: You said that your git repos are on vsts, no? if you have 20+ repos you can clone the build definition and configure them, then all will run automatically.

Comment: Yes , i have some projects on VSTS and some on GitHub. My requirement is not to run scan for each build or something. I want to run this once in a month on each repo that i just get the schedule through some Script and it get run on every start of month then send me reports through emails automatically. I can see checkmarx has lot of plugins for TFS/VSTS/Teamcity etc ....

Comment: You don't build the code, you just use the "Build pipeline" to run the scans. you can also use Azure DevOps and in the Get sources get the code from GitHub.

Comment: You mean i am creating build definition for each project either on Vsts and GitHub. What about the auto scheduling of project , want to run this once in a month.

Comment: No problem, in each build definition choose on Scheduled and configure there to run once in a month.

Comment: Great- What about Git Hub Projects - They are not part of VSTS and running separately. How checkmark will run once in a month for Code Scan ?

Comment: In VSTS build definition you configure to take the code from GitHub.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!!

Comment: Just for a little understanding: What is " Checkmarx Endpoint" and when we further go into it , there is  "Connection name". have the url/login/password but what is this parameter meant for? any example?

Comment: Here is the error: System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Scan cannot be completed: Failed to get preset list: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.. ---> System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Scan cannot be completed: Failed to get preset list: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error..

LegacyVSTSPowerShellHost.exe completed with return code: -1.

Comment: Can you share which values you put on the Checkmarx task fields?

Comment: Display name=Security static source code analysis , Checkmarx Endpoint=CxWebClient(I donno what is the purpose of this value), Project Name=ProjectName(One of the projects checkmarx scan already have), Preset=Checkmarx default,team= taken from one of the project scan already created in checkmarx. REST OF Values are default.